Application of stability theorem in persistent homology
I'm currently studying some basic concepts of persistent homology used in topological data analysis (TDA). The stability theorem (in the form presented in the book i'm reading) roughly states that given two persistence diagram $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B}$ constructed over filtrations that satisfies the following conditions:

Rips filtration of metric spaces $\mathbb{X}, \mathbb{Y}$ whose Gromov-Hausdorff distance is $d_{GH}(\mathbb{X}, \mathbb{Y}) \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$
Čech filtration of metric spaces $\mathbb{X}, \mathbb{Y}$ whose Gromov-Hausdorff distance is $d_{GH}(\mathbb{X}, \mathbb{Y}) \leq\varepsilon$

satisfies the condition that their bottleneck distance $d_B(\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B}) \leq \varepsilon$
In TDA $\mathbb{X}, \mathbb{Y}$ are usually discrete datasets. Is it correct to assume that the application of the stability theorem in TDA is to distinguish between different datasets? What i'm saying is that given two persistence diagrams, if we find that they are too far apart (in the sense that their bottleneck distance is large), then we can be sure that $\mathbb{X}, \mathbb{Y}$ can't possibly be datasets obtained from "the same object".
The book i'm referring to is "introduction to persistent homology" by Ziga Virk.

Yes, your interpretation is correct!
